# Need help with $\int_{0}^\infty x^n\sin(bx)e^{-ax^2}\, dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I need help with this integral:

$$\int_{0}^\infty x^n \sin(bx)e^{-ax^2}\, dx$$
where $a, b \in \Bbb R$ and $n\in \Bbb N$.

*Mathematica* wasn't very helpful.

Comment: denote the integral in question by $I(a,b,n). $for even/odd values of $n$, consider derivatives w.r.t to $a$ of $I(a,b,0)$ and $I(a,b,1)$ respectivly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Mathematica wasn't very helpful.*

That's because $~\sin bx=\Im(e^{ibx}),~$ whereas the other exponential has $x^2$ in its exponent,

which is what ultimately made a simple solution in terms of the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) impossible.

---

Let $~I(a,b)~=~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\sin(bx)~e^{-ax^2}~dx,~$ $~J(a,b)~=~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\cos(bx)~e^{-ax^2}~dx,~$ evaluate both

in closed form, using [Gaussian integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) and [error functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function), then take full advantage of

the fact that $n\in\mathbb N.~$ Notice that, depending on the parity of *n*, the initial integral can be

written as $~\dfrac{d^k}{da^k}~I(a,b),~$ for $n=2k,~$ or as $~\dfrac d{db}~\dfrac{d^k}{da^k}~J(a,b),~$ for $n=2k+1.$